# Application hangs on mocked method call

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, void

I'm trying to mock my `AuthenticationManager` class. I do so as below:

```
AuthenticationManager authManager = Mockito.mock(AuthenticationManager.class);
```

I only want to mock one of its methods, `PerformSignInAsync`. This method returns `void`. One of the arguments passed to this method is a handler and it needs to have its `onComplete` event called. I am trying to do so with an `ArgumentCaptor` as below:

```
ArgumentCaptor<AuthenticationResponseHandler> authResponseCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AuthenticationResponseHandler.class);
```

Below is how I've approached mocking the method I want mocked. When the test reaches the real method I've stepped through with the debugger and it is being invoked by Mockito. So I think the issue must be with my triggering of the `onComplete` call. **The application just hangs with no exception raised once the real** `PerformSignInAsync` **has been called.**

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            AuthenticationResponseHandler handler = (AuthenticationResponseHandler) args[4];
            // The line below is what I want triggered
            handler.onComplete(AuthenticationOperation.SignIn, responseToReturn);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(authManager).PerformSignInAsync(
            anyString(),
            anyString(),
            anyBoolean(),
            Matchers.any(UserLOBSystemType.class),
            authResponseCaptor.capture(),
            anyString(),
            anyString());
```

I've also tried triggering `onComplete` with the below code, to no avail:

```
    authResponseCaptor.capture().onComplete(AuthenticationOperation.SignIn, responseToReturn);
```

Comment: What about your handler, is it a mock also? can you provide a thread dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was referencing a different instance of `authManager` in the block of code in my question than what was being used in the real method. As a result the mock wasn't being triggered.